# Correct usage of Infinitive

Tags: grammar

Can we use to after a past form of verb?
Example : I called **to** Rohini

Comment: Even in  the present tense, *call to* someone is incorrect or at least awkward. This is a NARQ.

Comment: This has nothing to do with infinitives. In an infinitive, the "to" is placed before the verb, not after the verb.

Comment: *To* here is not an infinitive marker. It's a simple preposition.

Comment: And yes you can use an infinitive after a past tense: _I told him to call me._

Answer (score 1):

It's idiomatic English to say these:

> I **called** Rohini.
>   I **[called out to](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/call-out)** Rohini.
>   I **shouted** {to / at} Rohini.

The phrase "**call to**" is normally followed by words like "*arms, action, order,* and *prayer*".